# Spacing Issue in CollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I've an issue I'm using the collectionView inside the tableview but I'm very confused regarding how to customize the each sell size,width and spacing see the screenshot my cell text is cutting. I've different categories regarding food and I want to show the products according to categories and also want border radius on each cell and shadow colour. In the screenshot each cell has background colour,image and text is not showing properly thanks in advance.[image]

MyCode:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        switch row {
        case 0:
            return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.bounds.width / 2 , height: self.bounds.height)
        case 1:
            return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.bounds.width / 3, height: self.bounds.height)
        case 2:
            return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.bounds.width / 1 - 50, height: self.bounds.height)
        default:
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
```

Image Contraints[image]

TextField Constaints[image]

Comment: There is obviously issue with Autolayout. Please share you image and textLabel constraints.

Comment: I've update the question see the screenshots of constrains basically I'm using the kingfisher pod for images.

Comment: Please Add bottom constraint for imageView. This will fix issue.

Comment: Sorry I've applied but it's not working still text is cutting.

Comment: Make the number of lines to 0 for label